# Error importing the installed pygame module

Tags: python, pygame, spyder

I'm currently doing a project on my school pc and I want to use `pygame`, since I have experience with `pygame`. I have downloaded `pygame` using this line in the command prompt `python -m pip install -U pygame --user` when I try this line `python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens` that is used to see if `pygame` is downloaded right, it works fine.

But, when I import it in the project I get this error message

> File "C:/Users/user/Documents/Programming/test.py", line 10, in
>   
>       import pygame
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

extra info:
I use Spyder
It is a Windows pc

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you check if this computer has more than a version of `python`? Maybe you installed in python 2 and trying to run with python 3 or the opposite

Answer (score 0):

If you have used pygame before this, then have a look if you have any files named `pygame.py` as I had the same problem as you and my problem was naming a file the same as a core module so check that.

I have done the commands that you put and on the `python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens`. I got a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'`.

When I changed the second command to `python` instead of `python3` it worked after I installed pygame like this `pip install pygame` to uninstall pygame from how you did it when you install pygame change it to uninstall then try this version.