# why wont python pygame wont work in spyder?

Tags: python, pygame, spyder

I recently downloaded pygame on my school pc(I have experience with it before), but when I try to open a window it does not work and are black even though I colored the window in the code.

I even copied this code:

```
import pygame
background_colour = (255,255,255)
(width, height) = (300, 200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tutorial 1')
screen.fill(background_colour)
pygame.display.flip()
running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
```

But it does the same thing.

Extra:

I use Spyder with python 3.6

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I saw this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078224/error-importing-the-installed-pygame-module) of yours earlier. If you managed to fix that problem, would be nice if you give feedback there :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code work in my mac. If you are in Windows, try to restart the PC. Also, try to execute your example from a command line.